# Several python libraries for causal impact analysis based on R causal impact but which one should I use?

Tags: r, time-series, python, granger-causality, causalimpact

My question: I liked the Google causalimpact package in R and want to do the same work in Python. Which package should I use?

The very first library I saw is a port of Google's R causal impact package, perhaps the first:

- [pycausalimpact 0.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/pycausalimpact/). But the repository has disappeared (but
  there is still a medium.com tutorial online and the Python package can be installed).

There is a more active development:

- [causalimpact 0.2.6.](https://pypi.org/project/causalimpact/): There is a living community in this case. Interesting that it refers to the above one.

But there is a third one too:

- [tfp-causalimpact](https://github.com/google/tfp-causalimpact) is more close to Google, but still not official. I noticed it is based on the TensorFlow prob. model., but I see no more difference.

I tried to search for white papers with comparison, but there is no such paper. I'm new at this topic, so to have a picture in my mind is challenging.

Comment: Have you tried them?  Any issues you run into?

Comment: Another option is to work with a mix of python and R.  The `reticulate` package in R, paired with RStudio / Rmarkdown, makes it easy to switch back and forth between python and R.